# Remove _x005F, x_000D and _x000d from field in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to remove _x005F,_x000D and _x000d from the field in oracle

Answer (score 1):

Fast:

```sql
replace(replace(replace(col, '_x005F') ,'_x000D'), '_x000d')
```

Shorter and clearer, but slower:

```sql
regexp_replace(col, '(_x005F|_x000D|_x000d)')
```